Does Lipschitz continuity preserve Lebesgue measurability between $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ when $d\neq m$?
Question:
Suppose $d,m$ are two distinct natural numbers and $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is $K$-Lipschitz. Is it true that for each Lebesgue measurable set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, the set $f(E)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is also Lebesgue measurable?

Context and Attempt
It is well known that a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ preserves Lebesgue measurability when $d=m$. However, I am not sure if this is true when $d\neq m$, since in the proof of the case $d=m$, one proves that $f$ must map null set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ to null set in $\mathbb{R}^m$, which is just false when $d>m$. So this leaves me wondering, does Lipschitz function between $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ also preserve Lebesgue measurability when $d\neq m$? Or one can create a counter-example?

If $d\leq m$ it is true (direct estimate with rectangles/cubes). You can also consider locally-Lipschitz maps.

Consider the Lipschitz function $f(x,y) = x$ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. For any non-measurable set $E$ in $\mathbb R$, $E \times \{0\}$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^2$ (because it has measure $0$), and $E = f(E \times \{0\})$.  Similar examples for $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^m$ whenever $d > m$.
